# Function App Infra Bicep deploy wipes Function App code

Tags: azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-bicep

I am relatively new to Bicep and at the moment I have one DevOps repo containing a Function App project (with my code) and a main.bicep file (specifying the Infra).  I then have two pipelines configured for this repo.  One Pipeline runs to deploy the infra (on change of the bicep file) using the main.bicep file which provisions three resources:

- Microsoft.Web/serverfarms (hosting plan)
- Microsoft.Insights/components (app insights)
- Microsoft.Web/sites (Function app)

I then have a second code pipeline which triggers on commits to the Function App project and then builds, publishes code and deploys to Dev.

The issue I have is when the Infra pipeline reruns in Incremental mode (if I add a change to the Function App infra such as assigning a subnet to it) it seems to wipe my code and the Functions in the Function App disappear.  I then have to rerun the code deploy pipeline also to reinstate the actual code.  I don't understand why changing a "setting" on the Infra side of the Function App removes the zipped up code previously published to it.  I do not trigger the code pipeline on purpose after the Infra one as no code/functionality is changing so I would expect the Function App setting to be updated (and be VNET integrated in my example) and the code just to remain as is.

My Bicep "what-if" shows the Function App (Microsoft.Web/sites) will be modified with some properties created and modified.  The fact it shows modified at the Function App level to me would imply it will do the property changes it is mentioning (some creates and modifies) and leave everything else as is.

Anyone got any ideas?  My last resort will be to deploy the last successful published build artifact as part of the Infra pipeline but again, I was not expecting having to redeploy code everytime I change a setting.

**EDIT**

Was solved by the question asked here [Azure Function App infra redeployment makes existing functions in app fail because of missing requirements and also delete previous invocations data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74266226/azure-function-app-infra-redeployment-makes-existing-functions-in-app-fail-becau?rq=1)

Comment: could you please share your bicep code ? also are you using azure devops ? would yoube able to share the yaml taks you are using ?

Comment: Thanks Thomas - was solved as per above using the website_run_from_package app setting

Answer (score 0):

As you are running the Bicep deployment in Incremental mode and in the same pipeline, The Infrastructure is getting redeployed again, As a workaround, You can create your Infrastructure pipeline that deploys the Function app in a separate stage and Function app deployment in Separate stage. I tried deploying the Bicep File that deploys function resource in a separate stage in my release pipeline and Function Trigger code deployment in separate stage. This Isolates the Deployment and the Code deployment remains separate.

**My Release pipeline:-**

[image]

[image]

Output:-

[image]

[image]

Stage 1 YAML Code:-

```yaml
steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'SID subscription xxxxxxxxxxx'
    subscriptionId: 'xxxx8-xxxxb6e97cb2a7'
    resourceGroupName: 'silicon0-rg'
    location: 'Australia East'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_HTTPdotnetazfunc/main.bicep'
```

[image]

Now, ***I deployed the Function Trigger Code in another stage in same release pipeline:-***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Stage2 YAML:-

```yaml
steps:
- task: AzureFunctionApp@2
  displayName: 'Azure Function App Deploy: fnappr3aj3jeixj4tg'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'subscription id'
    appType: functionApp
    appName: fnappr3aj3jeixj4tg
    package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_HTTPdotnetazfunc/HTTPdotnetazfunc'
```

Different stages where I have kept the deployment as manual:-

[image]

You can also trigger your YAML pipeline in different stages. First Infra Stage and Second Build and Deploy Stage. [**Reference**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

One alternative is also to convert your Bicep File into ARM template and store the state of your deployment in ARM deployments.

Comment: Thanks Siddhesh - solved as per above using the app setting website_run_from_package

Comment: Voted this answer down as it mismatches terminology (Classic Release and YAML Pipelines), not sure if actually answers the question  and if going down this route the stages should have a dependency on each other if going to be in the same release.

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong, If we use above method, Both the stages are already connected with each other as they are in the same release pipeline. Instead of triggering them manually, If we trigger it auromatically, Any changes done in the stage 1 example- Enabling Vnet integration, The Vnet will be integrated in the Function app and then the stage 2 will deploy the code, Without removing the trigger. This way, The code will always be deployed even after the Function app is changed in stage 1.

Comment: I have given the YAML Pipeline code, And also gave one Document to run those YAML pipelines in stages connected to each other in same pipeline. This way, We can use variables from stage 1 in the yaml pipeline and use it in stage 2 to deploy the code in the same function app.Release pipelines makes it easier to deploy the resources in stages as it can be done UI based, Thus I used this approach.